# Record Count in the table is not displayed correctly while using datatable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatable

I am generating a table dynamically based on the results return from the query, everything is fine table is getting generated and datatable is showing up correctly.But the count of records  is wrong.The problem here is if i am getting 10 records it is showing 9 records in the count. But 10 records are present in the table.
Please help me in this regards.
My code:
PHP Code

```
mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
$query_getcolumns = $qry;
$getcolumns = mysql_query($query_getcolumns, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getcolumns = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcolumns);
$totalRows_getcolumns = mysql_num_rows($getcolumns);
echo $totalRows_getcolumns;
```

Table Code

```
if (($getcolumns)||(mysql_errno == 0))  
{  
  echo "<table width='50%' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' align='center' id='sample_2'>
  <thead><tr>";  
  if (mysql_num_rows($getcolumns)>0)  
  {  
          //loop thru the field names to print the correct headers  
          $i = 0;  
          while ($i <  mysql_num_fields($getcolumns))  
          {  
       echo "<th align='center'>". mysql_field_name($getcolumns, $i) . "</th>";  
       $i++;  
    }  
    echo "</tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    //display the data  
    while ($rows =  mysql_fetch_assoc($getcolumns))  
    {  
      echo "<tr>";  
      foreach ($rows as $data)  
      {  
        echo "<td align='center' width=''>". $data . "</td>";  
      }  
    }  
  }else{  
    echo "<td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr>";  
  }  
  echo "</tbody></table>";  
}else{  
  echo "Error in running query :". mysql_error();  
}
```

Comment: can you show the ` $qry`

Comment: $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);


$qry = " SELECT `Asset Id`,";
$qry .= $data; 
$qry .= " from CompletedetailsTrans";

Comment: just do `echo $qry;` and see the query and put this query in phpmyadmin and check how many rows are you getting. Also use `msqli` instead of `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in your PHP code, fourth line is doing problem that is

```
$row_getcolumns = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcolumns);
```

Actually when ever you call mysql_fetch_assoc it fetches the record from the top and move the internal pointer to next record.

Therefore, you had already lost one record before creating your table

This line seems to be useless in your code. Comment this line and try.